# RN pod install occurs the error message "machine `arm64-apple' not recognized" regardless of Rosseta or not

Tags: ios, react-native, rubygems, cocoapods

I'm suffering from the error message below.

```
<PATH>Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/Release/Flipper-Glog/0.3.6-1dfd6/missing: Unknown `--is-lightweight' option
Try `<PATH>Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/Release/Flipper-Glog/0.3.6-1dfd6/missing --help' for more information
configure: WARNING: 'missing' script is too old or missing
Invalid configuration `arm64-apple-darwin21.4.0': machine `arm64-apple' not recognized
configure: error: /bin/sh ./config.sub arm64-apple-darwin21.4.0 failed
```

Open terminal and `arch -x86_64 pod install` is not working.

Open terminal as Rosetta Mode and `pod install` also is not working.

I guess it is related to something bug with libraries with Flipper-Glog however, I don't have any idea where I start finding to solve this issue. (machine `arm64-apple' not recognized)

Could you give me some advice about to solve this issue?

Thanks!